# HTML row style incorrect in email, but not Out-File

Tags: powershell

Source for the code: https://jamesdatatechq.wordpress.com/2014/12/23/how-to-create-an-html-table-from-powershell/

Good Afternoon,

Using the above tutorial, I have created the following script to test the connections of various servers:

```
$Style = "
<style>
    BODY{background-color:#b0c4de;}
    TABLE{border-width: 1px;border-style: solid;border-color: black;border-collapse: collapse;}
    TH{border-width: 1px;padding: 3px;border-style: solid;border-color: black;background-color:#778899}
    TD{border-width: 1px;padding: 3px;border-style: solid;border-color: black;}
    tr:nth-child(odd) { background-color:#d3d3d3;} 
    tr:nth-child(even) { background-color:white;}    
</style>
"
#Cell Color - Logic
$StatusColor = @{False = ' bgcolor="Red">Offline<';True = ' bgcolor="Green">Online<';}

#Check Online
$subject = "Online Test at " + (Get-Date -Format g)
$body = (import-csv "C:\AutoTasks\servers.txt" | % {new-object psobject -property @{ComputerName=$_.Computer;Description=$_.Description; Reachable=(test-connection -computername $_.Computer -quiet -count 1)} }  | ConvertTo-HTML -AS Table -Fragment -PreContent '<h2>Online Status</h2>'|Out-String) 

#Cell Color - Find\Replace
$StatusColor.Keys | foreach { $body = $body -replace ">$_<",($StatusColor.$_) }

$main = ConvertTo-HTML -head $Style -PostContent $body | Out-String
Send-MailMessage -From "xxxxxxxxxx" -To "xxxxxxxxxxx" -Subject $subject -Body $main -BodyAsHtml -SmtpServer "xxxxxx"
```

If I run this, I get the email, I get the ping tests, I get the table, and the green / red conditional formatting. What I don't get is the row colour formatting, which is covered in the following lines:

```
tr:nth-child(odd) { background-color:#d3d3d3;} 
tr:nth-child(even) { background-color:white;}
```

Now, if I comment out the bottom 2 lines and add the following line, outputting to file instead of mail, I get all formatting present and correct:

```
ConvertTo-HTML -head $Style -PostContent $body | Out-File c:\temp\online.html
```

Is there a reason that row formatting is being lost during the creation of the email?

EDIT

Additional.

In the email output, I've notice a small box in the top left corner of the mail, which I suspect is where all the formatting is going. This isn't on the html out-file, so I suspect the problem is in the bottom 2 lines.

Comment: If you're using Microsoft Outlook to view this, it still uses Microsoft Word for HTML rendering and as such, `nth-child` it won't work. Running your code above I still have the issue on Outlook 2016. You can see what CSS is supported in various email clients [here](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/). That being said, despite it mentioning outlook.com supporting it, it doesn't render correctly on https://outlook.office.com either.

Comment: @Robin Many thanks.