# Why do CSS colors disappear in PowerShell ConvertTo-HTML email?

Tags: css, powershell, outlook

I'm working on creating a daily report that collects info from a database and sends it out in an email. The report is formatted fine when I output it into a file.html, however in an email it doesn't show the styling. In outlook it's missing the colors, in gmail it misses all the CSS.

The convert to html portion is:

```
$mailTable = $callData | ConvertTo-Html -Property "Support Rep",Time,System,Area,"Column X",Description,Resolution -head $css
$twTable = $qualityNums | ConvertTo-Html -Property "Support Rep","Date/Time","Quality Reference" -head $css
```

my $css variable is:

```
$css = " 
 <style>
 table {
  border: 2px solid #1C6EA4;
  background-color: #EEEEEE;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: left;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
%trimmed out CSS %
 </style>
 "
```

And the email body itself is:

```
If($containsQualityInfo -eq $True){
    $emailBody = "Recent Support calls below: <br><br><p>$mailTable</p><br><br><br>The following quality records have been opened:<br><br><p>$twTable</table></p>" 
  }
```

Here are pictures of what it looks like in the file, and what it looks like in outlook: 
In a file:
[image: in file output]

And in Outlook:
[image: In Outlook]

Why do the colors not show up in Outlook when they appear to be working in the html file?

Comment: Have you checked the message source code in Outlook? It might be that it's stripping out your css

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen good suggestion, I checked the source in both the html file and outlook and they are the same.

Answer (score 0):

Update: Apparantly it's because Outlook doesn't render all the CSS I ommited from the question correctly. In there was nth-chil (even); for the row colorization. Problem is also described here.

[HTML row style incorrect in email, but not Out-File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42859056/html-row-style-incorrect-in-email-but-not-out-file)

Guess I get to have fun refactoring!